# Ember nested route template with conditional HTML in place of outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a nested route that looks like:

```
/products
/products/:productId
```

And the `/products` template renders with a sidebar listing all the products, and a "main" content `<div>` in the center that is populated with a specific product when clicked. ie:

```
<div id="productsSidebar">
    ... navigation tree ...
</div>
<div id="mainContainer">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

However, I would like for the `{{outlet}}` to be replaced with a message like

> Please select a product to the left.

When there is no child route, ie. we're just looking at `/products` and the main `<div>` is otherwise completely empty.

I haven't found any reference/tutorial demonstrating if this is possible - is there a standard way to render a "default" block of HTML if there no outlet available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the products index route template to display that html text. You may need to generate the route with something like `ember g route products/index`